# Migration to spring boot 2.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

There is a service and a starter on the spring boot. I decided to migrate both of them to sb2. I transferred the starter, everything was fine, I uploaded it to the server, I registered a dependency in the service. However, there is a problem: java does not see dependencies on classes of a starter. In external libraries starter is present, classes are also present there, however in the service itself they seem to just not exist. Error on the compilation stage: `can not find symbol ...` P.S. with all other libraries all ok. 
What i had done: 
   In starter: 
     In `build.gradle`:
     In `buildscript` upgared SB version, Add `apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'`, add

```
dependencyManagement {
   imports {
      mavenBom 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Finchley.RELEASE'
   }
}
```

After all push to server. In service I have done same things. What I missed?
P.S. Sorry for my English

Comment: white space in `spring-cloud- dependencies` ?

Comment: no:) Bad copypast

Comment: And you want us to guess which errors you have? Upgrading dependencies to newer versions probably also include changed/renamed/moved classes. Follow the [Spring Boot 2 Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide) which is probably a bit more then simply upgrading dependencies.

Comment: Look, in starter all dependencies are latest, gradle loads all dependencies. In service all dependencies are also latest. Problem started when I trying to add dependency to my starter in service. Maybe migration of custom starter to spring boot 2 have some unusual features, witch I missed